# Orbeon Forms attaching xforms-disabled class to all fields after upgrading versions

Tags: orbeon

I am coming across an issue with getting older, previously working Orbeon forms to display in my Liferay portlet after upgrading to a new Orbeon Forms version.

My current environment:
Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.2.1 CE GA2, running on Tomcat-9.0.17

Upgraded Orbeon Forms 2016.2.1.201609272302 PE -> 2019.2.2.202003311635 PE, Orbeon Api and Orbeon Form Builder running on Tomcat-8.5.20, java version "1.8.0_192"

I started out by using an existing applicationName/formName, and after encountering too many errors related to data-migration (which I did expect) decided to start simple by duplicating an existing form, backing the old form up, and proceeding to use the existing form as a testing form with a limited amount of fields (one section with one input field).
[Snapshot of Form in formbuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq5Lq.jpg)

The portlet in the app shows the title of the form, but all content divs/spans have the “xforms-disabled” css class attached, and are hidden.
[Form as viewed deployed in Liferay portlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df8ww.jpg)

Orbeon starts up without issues. Nothing of note in the orbeon api logs.

The logger levels are all set to Debug. The orbeon.log file has no instances of xforms-disabled and hundreds of instances of xforms-enabled.

[Link to DEBUG orbeon.log (large)](https://zerobin.net/?5505eec508069219#yhU4qRbheoXFx+cs+5kTshJ1CugBT1+JN+rgiPOVz6U=)

The endpoint that would bring back all the data for the form that would be embedded into the portlet looks like it has valid data:
/orbeon-api/fr/NRPP_Roads_FSR_Modification/roads_notification_of_fsr_modification/edit/?orbeon-embeddable=true

And then the end result on the page is as shown:

```html
<div id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡xf-571" class="xforms-group">
   <h2 class="fr-section-title"><span id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡xf-576" class="fr-section-label xforms-control xforms-output xforms-output-appearance-minimal"><span class="xforms-help"></span><span id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡xf-576≡≡c" class="xforms-output-output">Notification of FSR Mod Works</span><span class="xforms-hint"></span></span></h2>
   <div id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡switch" class="xforms-update-full xforms-switch">
      <span class="xforms-case-selected">
         <div id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡xf-579" class="fr-section-content xxforms-animate xforms-group">
            <div id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid" class="xbl-component xbl-fr-grid">
               <table id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡xf-589" class="fr-grid fr-grid-2 fr-grid-rrs_.fsr_.section_ fr-norepeat xforms-group" role="presentation">
                  <tbody class="fr-grid-body">
                     <tr class="fr-grid-tr">
                        <td id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡xf-592" class="fr-grid-td xforms-group"><span id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡rrs_.fsr_.section_.text-control" class="fr-grid-1-1 xforms-control xforms-input xforms-disabled"><label class="xforms-mediatype-text-html xforms-disabled xforms-label" for="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡rrs_.fsr_.section_.text-control≡xforms-input-1"></label><input id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡rrs_.fsr_.section_.text-control≡xforms-input-1" type="text" name="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡rrs_.fsr_.section_.text-control≡xforms-input-1" value="" class="xforms-input-input"><span class="xforms-disabled xforms-alert"></span><span class="xforms-disabled xforms-hint"></span></span></td>
                        <td id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡xf-597" class="fr-grid-td xforms-group"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
               <div class="" id="_orbeonformsproxyportlet_WAR_nrssfsmartformsportletorbeonproxyportlet_rrs_.fsr_-section≡rrs_.fsr_.section_-grid≡xf-599"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem to matter how many fields or types of fields or sections/grids I add to the test page, they all render with the xforms-disabled class attached.

Why is the xforms-disabled class attached to the fields and how do I fix the form to prevent that from happening? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is that `/orbeon-api/fr/` endpoint something custom? I wonder if it could be a data format issue. Can you, from the portlet, save new data, and then read it back?

Comment: I don't think the endpoint is custom? Wasn't able to find docs on the endpoint, but it  lines up with the appName/formName standard? The og form I'm able to somewhat get to display when I change Form Settings: Simple Data Migration to "Enabled", and after I had swapped out all the fields I had that were used for calculations that were tagged with "xforms-disabled" class for the Orbeon 2019 "Hidden" field. I was still running into errors though. So we decided to just start small with just one simple field as above. Unable to save and read back data in either the og form or the simple one.